# What exactly does a web developer do? And are there any textbooks that describe it?

Tags: word-request

1) Which verbs can I use to describe correctly the web developer's activities?

I need to decribe activity when a web developer creates a site for some (small) company at first and then maintains its work and improves it regularly.  Are there any one verb or two verbs together or any word combinations?

**Edit**: So can I answer when somebody asks: 'What exactly do you do?'

> I am a web developer. I work for a small company. I code, develop and maintain their website.

2) Is there any good up-to-date vocabulary textbook for English learners in IT or any useful links about it?

Comment: I don't think there is a special verb for what they do. They either *program* or *maintain* (as you said). They *write/design* software. They also *code* and *develop*. Implement different features.

Comment: http://www.techterms.com/ Have a look at the link for the IT Dictionary you are looking for. Hope it can help

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at some job offers for web developers - you'll get a good selection of the types of things they do, including the verbs they go with - and you'll be able to narrow it down to exactly the type of web developer work you mean (for instance, I personally do a lot of things that many "typical" developers might not do).

Obvious choices include: *program, develop, code, (re)design (layout, database, structure), build (websites, apps), maintain, implement (features), restructure, conduct (surveys, feasibility analysis), install (sites, modules), write (code, modules), test, fix (bugs), translate (business needs into technical solutions), optimize (performance)*...

As for books combining ESL & IT, the only ones I know about are "Oxford English for Information Technology", "Cambridge Professional English in Use ICT" and "Infotech: English for computer users", also from Cambridge. But most introductory books for computer science should have a good list of vocabulary in the form of a glossary at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no **single** term that defines that you code, design and maintain. However, the closest is **webmaster** which'd include maintaining and looking after the website as a whole. Also note that webmaster also looks after **designing** and any problem in coding. [Webmaster has many roles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmaster) and this term will not restrict your designation to just a web designer/developer.

If you think that webmaster is more into *maintaining* the website, you may just add a word *web developer* and this'll fulfill your purpose.

> I'm a web developer and a webmaster.

Whether you want to give extra information about the size of your company, that's up to you.